# Does the product of two constants get computed every time it is executed? 

Tags: c++, processing-efficiency, performance

For example, if I have:

```
if(x < 2*0.025) { ... }
```

Does the `2*0.025` get computed every time? Or does a `0.05` get substituted in so that the multiplication operation doesn't have to run every time?

In other words, is it more efficient to use `0.05` instead of `2*0.025`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every compiler I know implements [*constant folding*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding), i.e. calculates constant expressions at compile time, so there is no difference. The standard, however, does not mandate it:

> A constant expression can be evaluated during translation rather than runtime, and accordingly may be used in any place that a constant may be.

You can explicitly disable this optimization with some compilers. For example, `-frounding-math` disables constant folding for floating point expressions in gcc.

Answer (score 0):

Constant expressions are precomputed.